# SVC with class_weight in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to use `class_weight` to create a weighted SVC classifier in sikit-learn. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if I'm configuring correctly my model. Please consider the example below:

```
x = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,0]])
y = np.array([1,1,0])

cw = {}
for l in set(y):
    cw[l] = np.sum(y == l)
print(cw)

m = SVC(probability = True, max_iter = 1000, class_weight = cw)
m = m.fit(x,y)
```

I obtained the model:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight={0: 1, 1: 2}, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=1000, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

With `class_weight={0: 1, 1: 2}` corresponding to the number of data points in each class.

**QUESTION:** Is it correct to proceed in this way?

Comment: It's worth noting that the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) recommends against using lower case 'L' as a variable (as in your loop). "In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the numerals one and zero. When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead"

Comment: After getting stung by the suggestion @G.Anderson mentioned (I read np.sum(y == l) as np.sum(y == 1)) I edited the question to use i for index.  Added this comment so above comment doesn't seem out of place

Comment: ...my wording was poor in the first comment and I didn't notice until after the editing window closed.  I should have said "After getting stung by the **problem @G.Anderson highlighted in their post**...".  G.Anderson made an excellent suggestion that did not sting :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have a 2:1 ratio of class labels, this weighting appears to be correct.

One other thing you can do if you don't want to manually calculate the class weights is to pass `class_weight='balanced'` and let the `SVC` balance the weights for you

Comment: Unless I misinterpret something, `class_weight='balanced'` does the opposite of what the OP described.  OP's method increases the weight on records in the common classes (`y==1` receives a higher class_weight than `y==0`), whereas `'balanced'` does the reverse (`'balanced'` decreases the weight of records in the common class in order to balance the weight of the whole class).  Fitting the above model from OP with `class_weight='balanced'` results in `m.class_weight_==[1.5, 0.75]`, not `[1., 2.]`